# Difference between session.socket.io and express.session.socket.io in node

Tags: node.js, socket.io

To share express session into the socket.io on listener ,naturally use two library session.socket.io and express.session.socket.io what is the main difference between them ?
I read npm and github but not get any clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

`express.session.socket.io` allows you to have a single unified session object that can be used by either Express request handlers or by socket.io message handlers.  Creating this connection between Express and socket.io allows you to do things like send to a given user's socket.io connection from within an Express request handler.

It creates a connection between the socket.io connection and an incoming Express request which would not normally exist.  It also allows your socket.io handlers to have access to your Express session objec which may contain useful user-specific state or information.

`session.socket.io` is an out of date attempt to do something similar.  It says: "compatible with express 3, connect 2 and socket.io 0.9" which are all old versions.

Comment: @ZahidRahman - Did this answer your question?  If it did, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn your some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.